# Mapping from many-to-many in database to one-to-many in domain

Tags: .net, many-to-many, entity-framework-6, one-to-many, ef-fluent-api

I have a mapping challange in Entity Framework.

In the database I have a many-to-many relation between two tables with a intermediate table with the PK of the both as bellow:

[image: Many-To-Many with Dependents intermediated table]

I need to map this relation to a one-to-many domain entities relation as bellow:

[image: One-To-Many entities relation]

How can I map this using Fluent API?

Comment: Does it need to be mapped one-to-many or many-to-many with only one navigational property?

Comment: You can't map this as one-to-many because that requires a direct foreign key.

Comment: I need to map to one-to-many, I can not add a property just to have a foreign key...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a navigation property and set the Dependents table in the model:

```
public class Title
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Person> Dependents { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Title> Titles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Title>()
            .HasMany<Person>(t => t.Dependents)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(d =>
            {
                d.MapLeftKey("Title_Id");
                d.MapRightKey("Person_Id");
                d.ToTable("Dependents");
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Max! Works as expected.